# How do I fix this output?

Tags: c

I am having an issue with the outputs of my code and can't figure out the problem or what needs to be added/taken away. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int array[100], n, c, d, swap;

  printf("Enter number of elements to be sorted:");
  scanf("%d", &n);





  for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);

  for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
  {
    for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
    {
      if (array[d] > array[d+1]) 
      {
        swap       = array[d];
        array[d]   = array[d+1];
        array[d+1] = swap;
      }
    }
  }


  for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
  {

    printf("Enter next element:");
     printf("%d\n", array[c]);

  }



  for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
  {
      printf("%d\n", array[c]);
  }



  return 0;
}
```

And this is the output

```
Enter·number·of·elements·to·be·sorted:8↵
Enter·next·element:8↵
1↵
Enter·next·element:7↵
2↵
Enter·next·element:6↵
3↵
Enter·next·element:1↵
4↵
Enter·next·element:2↵
5↵
Enter·next·element:3↵
6↵
Enter·next·element:4↵
7↵
Enter·next·element:5↵
8↵
1↵
2↵
3↵
4↵
5↵
6↵
7↵
8↵
```

I don't want the number under each line of the "Enter the next element: " lines and cannot figure out how to get rid of them. Please and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code :

```
for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
{ 
 printf("Enter next element:");
 printf("%d\n", array[c]);
}
```

Remove the second printf() statement.

```
for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
{
printf("Enter next element:");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
{ 
 printf("Enter next element:");
 printf("%d\n", array[c]);
}
```

and replace:

```
  for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);
```

by:

```
  for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
  {
    printf("Enter next element: ");
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);
  }
```

This is really trivial.